# Monotouch Web Reference Namespace Issue

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have an ASP.net web service sitting on a server, and I have verified that it works properly via a small test client app in VS.

I went to add it in MonoDevelop to my MT application, (Trying both the ASP.net 2.0 and WCF declarations). Inside the "Add Web Reference" wizard, it finds the web service fine. But when I go to reference it, the app doesn't know it exists.

I went to look at it, and it seems when adding it, the namespace it's assigning to it is the title of my solution (which has spaces in it), but the namespace for each of my .cs files within my app contains no spaces.

Web Service Namespace (that it wont let me change): Ultimate GameDay 2011
MT Application Namespace: UltimateGameday2011.

So I manually went into the reference.cs file and took out the spaces. The app classes then saw my web reference object, but it still won't allow me to access any of its members.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this one out? My issue is very similar to this one, using vb in monodevelop 2.6 beta 2. At first, when referencing my web service (Dim check As New XDAServices), I had errors in monodevelop saying "Type XDAServices is not defined (BC30456)".
Now, since realising it requires the namespace ('UPNPODCapture', my solution name), I use UPNPODCapture.XDAServices but still get an error, "Type expected BC30182)". Your help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following link http://merbla.blogspot.com/2011/03/monotouch-with-json-using-aspnet-mvc.html

Its not a fix to your problem rather a method of creating web services that MonoTouch more easily works with.  In my experience ASMX and WCF services have been problematic when consuming in a Monotouch app.

If all else fails, try using the Silverlight service utility located in your programs folder

e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Tools\SlSvcUtil.exe